# Do I need a Three.Color() object or can I simply use an {r:xx, g:xx, b:xx} object of my own

Tags: object, colors, three.js, prototype

I have a color module I use for representing colors of most types. It would be trivial for it to have a Three.Color object which is simply an object with three r, g, b properties.

But the Three.Color has a prototype with several methods.

So the question is: can I use a plain {r:xx, g:xx, b:xx} object wherever Three needs a color? Or would it be best (avoid conversions) if I actually use a new Three.Color() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to your question depends on your case. The Three.js renderer uses attributes like [`.isColor`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Color.js#L73) to do lots of checks, so passing an object with just `{r, g, b}` values isn't going to work in lots of situations when the engine checks what type of object it's dealing with.

Also, if you set your renderer to handle gamma color-correction, it's going to require [`.convertLinearToGamma`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Color.js#L343). Plus probably several other occasions that I can't think of, so I think it's best if you just create a `THREE.Color` from the get-go to avoid running into lots of unwanted behavior in the future.